# Product solution to PDEs, graphical interpretation

Tags: waves, differential-equations

It seems to me that it is relatively easy to tell if a physical phenomenon, say the height of a wave, $U(t, x, y)$, represents a product solution to a PDE, i.e., is of the form T(t)*X(x)*Y(y), e.g. this wave is not the solution to a PDE obtained by the separation of variables.  I assume the answer to this question is obvious, but, I've been looking for a while and I haven't seen this simple interpretation.  What it says to me is that separation of variables doesn't work for most physics problems, and that's why everything has to be done numerically.

[image: central pulse reflected from boundary of a square drum]

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I don't think so, lots of classical physics is based on PDEs, e.g. heat transfer, stress and strain in materials, fluid dynamics, electrodynamics, so the question is does separation of variables help solve problems in those branches of physics.  I don't think it does because the performance of most physical systems can't be represented by a product of functions, and hence their models can't be solved using separation of variables.